# Multivariate time series model

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to forecast tax base (time series) based on 3 variables : tax break, inflows of earnings and economic profits.
I tried to use `auto.arima` with `xreg` but I got the error:

> No suitable ARIMA model found.

The tax break data is basically all zero's from 2011 to 2013, 2014 is 50,000, 2015 is 75,000 and all the following years it is 100,000. 
Also, the tax break is like each company gets 100,000$ exemption on its first 100,000$ profit. I really want to know it my model is correct or else how should I model this data? The code is below:

```
tb = ts(data1$Taxbreak, start = c(2001), frequency = 1)
inflows = ts(data1$`Inflow of earnings`, start = c(2001), frequency = 1)
ep = ts(data1$`Economic Profits`, start = c(2001), frequency = 1)

xreg = cbind(tb, inflows,ep)
colnames(xreg) <- c("taxbreak","inflows", "economic profit")
xreg

B =ts(data1$`GR Tax Base`, start = c(2001), frequency = 1)
Box.test(B, lag = 15, type = "Ljung-Box")#stationary
acf(B)

revfit<-auto.arima(B, xreg=xreg)
tsdisplay(residuals(revfit))


newtb = ts(forecasted1$Taxbreak, start = c(2017), frequency = 1)
newinflows = ts(forecasted1$`Inflow of earnings`, start = c(2017), frequency = 1)
newperep = ts(forecasted1$`Economic Profits`, start = c(2017), frequency = 1)
nnewxreg = cbind(newtb, newinflows, newep)
nnewxreg

fcast <- forecast(revfit, xreg = nnewxreg)
list(fcast)
plot(fcast)
tsdisplay(residuals(fcast))
accuracy(fcast)
```

This is the data that I used for to get to

```
revfit<-auto.arima(B, xreg=xreg)
tsdisplay(residuals(revfit))
```

and I got the error at this step.

```
Year    Taxbreak earnings   Profits    Tax Base
2001    $0.00   $5,332,463  762        32,222,803,774
2002    $0.00   $5,431,753  808       33,610,875,248
2003    $0.00   $5,643,742  979     30,835,183,333
2004    $0.00   $6,134,432  1,179   36,383,352,174
2005    $0.00   $6,433,098  1,375   48,219,466,667
2006    $0.00   $6,871,455  1,578   59,596,984,211
2007    $0.00   $7,265,704  1,609   60,346,996,997
2008    $0.00   $7,390,580  1,435   61,060,551,948
2009    $0.00   $7,171,789  1,237   64,854,063,604
2010    $0.00   $7,258,068  1,588   60,502,826,855
2011    $0.00   $7,581,240  1,782   61,554,035,336
2012    $0.00   $7,862,034  1,952   68,020,593,640
2013    $0.00   $7,903,139  2,006   75,653,752,650
2014    $1.00   $8,211,705  2,026   77,369,017,668
2015    $1.00   $8,625,298  2,098   73,887,957,597
2016    $1.00   9095703 2288.857    76,386,659,364
```

for the rest of the code I was planning to use the below data to be my `newxreg` to forecast the tax base from 2017 to 2020

```
Year  Taxbreak  earnings    Profits    
2017    $1.00   9330906     2,384
2018    $1.00   9566108     2,497
2019    $1.00   9801311     2,575
2020    $1.00   10036513    2,670
2021    $1.00   10271716    2,766
2022    $1.00   10506918    2,861
```

Comment: Where in your code does the error occur? Are you able to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Year     Taxbreak Inflow of earnings Economic Profits
2001 $0.00  $5,332,463  762
2002 $0.00  $5,431,753  808
2003 $0.00  $5,643,742  979
2004 $0.00  $6,134,432  1,179
2005 $0.00  $6,433,098  1,375
2006 $0.00  $6,871,455  1,578
2007 $0.00  $7,265,704  1,609
2008 $0.00  $7,390,580  1,435
2009 $0.00  $7,171,789  1,237
2010 $0.00  $7,258,068  1,588
2011 $0.00  $7,581,240  1,782
2012 $0.00  $7,862,034  1,952
2013 $0.00  $7,903,139  2,006
2014 $1.00  $8,211,705  2,026
2015 $1.00  $8,625,298  2,098
2016 $1.00  9095703 2,288

Comment: I used the above data for the below code                                                         tb = ts(data1$Taxbreak, start = c(2001), frequency = 1)
inflows = ts(data1$`Inflow of earnings`, start = c(2001), frequency = 1)
ep = ts(data1$`Economic Profits`, start = c(2001), frequency = 1)

xreg = cbind(tb, inflows,ep)
colnames(xreg) <- c("taxbreak","inflows", "economic profit")
xreg

B =ts(data1$`GR Tax Base`, start = c(2001), frequency = 1)
Box.test(B, lag = 15, type = "Ljung-Box")#stationary
acf(B)

revfit<-auto.arima(B, xreg=xreg)
tsdisplay(residuals(revfit))

Comment: i got the error at this step:                                                                             revfit<-auto.arima(B, xreg=xreg)